# Exercises whilst recovering from Achilles Tendonitis - how to get heartrate up to 80% for 30 minutes

Tags: heart-rate

I am recovering from Achilles tendonitis.
I need to get my heart rate up to 80% of the max, for 30 minutes in one session
.
On a treadmill, I get to this goal very easily, but I need to find alternatives while recovering.

Foot surgeon says I'm not allowed to perform any exercises that result in impact on the feet - e.g.:

- Do assault bike standing up
- Use the treadmill at all
- Jump rope

I tried the following with no/little success

- Assault bike sitting down- below 70% heart trate
- Elliptical machine
- Rowing machine
- Spinning cycle - dont get to 70% heartrate most of the time

I have access to

- Swimming pool
- Step machine (should i use this while recovering?)
- Weights (full gym)

I am keen on strengthening my core and legs, but need to do some sort of cardio.
I would love to combine weights and cardio in an exercise.

Comment: May I ask why are you hellbent on the 80% hr? Core (abdominal) is actually better trained with focused mid-slow reps

Comment: The 80% / 30minutes has helped me reach a great fitness level in the past 6 months, and is in line with fitness goals set by my medical aid for which I get rewarded.

Comment: I would hate for this to turn out into a debate whether 80% is good or not - it is a goal which has helped me get fit and i would like to keep it up so that when I have completed recovery, I can continue running again - where I know my heart-rate will be 80% for 30minutes. I am desperate to not lose my conditioning.